# Why does my child table tblOefenen2 didn't get updated after inserting data on cascade update?

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have two tables named tblOefenen(with primary key) and tblOefenen2 (with foreign key). I have dropped the foreign key earlies because i wanted to add the 'on update cascade' to the foreign key.

So what did:
 1. I have removed the constraint (foreign key) of tbloefenen2. 
 2 . I have added the new foreign key to the column ID, my primary key is on the column ID as well in the table tbloefenen:

```
begin tran
alter table tbloefenen2
ADD constraint pkoefenen2 FOREIGN KEY (ID)
references tbloefenen (ID)
on UPDATE cascade
rollback tran
```

3. I have inserted some data to the tbloefenen (primary key table): 
   Begin tran

```
    UPDATE tblOefenen
    set naam = 'anouk'
    where naam = 'Svenn'

    select *
    from tblOefenen

    rollback tran
```

4. Only the parent (primary key) table got updated after i have inserted the data above.. the tbloefenen2(with the foreign key) remained unchanged (where i expected to be an automatic update after the insert into the parent primary key table)

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: The foreign key is `ID`, not `naam`.

Comment: You only get a cascade if you change `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

`ON UPDATE CASCADE` only applies when you update the column in the foreign key, not other columns in the table. So if you do

```
UPDATE tblOefenen
SET ID = 10
WHERE ID = 20;

SELECT * 
FROM tblOefenen2;
```

then you will see that `ID = 10` changed to `ID = 20`.

Comment: Ah ok! thank you. But is there an other way that my data will automatically be inserted to the foreign key table when I am inserting data to the parent table? Otherwise my data will be incompleted.

Comment: You're not inserting anything, you're just updating an existing row. You could use a trigger to insert into the child table.

Comment: Excuse me, yes i mean inserting. I have built a trigger but i was also guessing when that was the only way. that makes things clear. Thank you very much